# Webpack dev server proxy not working for ws

Tags: webpack, websocket, proxy, webpack-dev-server

This is my webpack-dev-server configuration:

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    port: 3000,
    hot: false,
    inline: false,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    proxy: [
        {
            path: 'ws://',
            target: 'ws://localhost:9000',
            ws: true,
            secure: false,
        },
        {
            path: '/',
            target: 'http://localhost:9000',
            secure: false,
            changeOrigin: true,
        },
    ]
},
```

The thing is, that the ws requests are throwing this error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://api2/someSocket' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

What's wrong with my configuration?

Comment: did you solved this?